# Heroku: how to have it access multiple .js files

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, discord.js

[image: error]

I'm getting this error message on heroku and I think I'm getting it cause of Procfile.
[image: heroku]

I'm using Worker at the moment, but I'm trying to figure out how to have heroku access both index.js and ping.js. Unless I'm reading the error message completely wrong and this could be a different issue. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's my code for index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const music = require('@koenie06/discord.js-music');
const fs = require('fs');
const { dir } = require('console');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    shards: "auto",
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
    ]
});

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection();

//Command handler and aliases
fs.readdirSync('./commands/').forEach(dir => {
    //in the commands folder, we gonna check for the category
    fs.readdir(`./commands/${dir}`, (err, files) => {
        //console log error(catch error)
        if(err)throw err;
        //checking if the files ends with .js if its a javascript file
        var jsFiles = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js');
        //if there is no commands in the file it will return
        if(jsFiles.length <= 0) {
            console.log("Can't find any commands");
            return;
        }

        jsFiles.forEach(file => {
            //console the loaded commands
            var fileGet = require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`);
            console.log(`[COMMAND HANDLER] - File ${file} was loaded`);
            //gonna let the commands run
            try {
                bot.commands.set(fileGet.help.name, fileGet);
                // it search in the commands folder if there is any aliases
                fileGet.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
                    bot.aliases.set(alias, fileGet.help.name);
                })
            } catch(err) {
                //catch error in console
                return console.log(err);
            }
        })
    })
})


/**
 * ECHO STUFF
 */


//slash command to echo 
bot.on('ready', async () => {
    bot.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: "Tedi", type: "WATCHING"}] });
    console.log("bye");
    const data = {
        name: 'echo',
        description: 'Echo your text',
        options: [{
            name: 'text',
            type: 'STRING',
            description: 'The user input',
            required: true,
        }],
    };
const command = await bot.guilds.cache.get('872986148681703444')?.commands.create(data);
})

bot.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type == 'DM') return

    let prefix = '~'
    let messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
    let cmd = messsageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    //it will make the cmd work with his original name and his aliases
    let commands = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)));
    if(commands) {
        if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return
        commands.run(bot, message, args, prefix);
    }
})

//interactionCreate for echo slash command
bot.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    /**
     * isButton() used to check if its a button
     * isCommand() used to check if its a slash command
     * isSelectMenu() used to check if its a dropdown menu
     * isMessageComponent()
     */
    if(interaction.isCommand()) {
        if(interaction.commandName === 'echo') {
            const text = interaction.options.getString('text');
            await interaction.reply({ content: text, ephemeral: false}); //if ephemeral if true, it would make the slash command private
        }
    }
})

bot.login(process.env.token);
```

Here is my ping.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args, prefix) => {
    message.channel.send("pong")
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ping",
    aliases: ["p"]
}
```

Comment: Its likely not a heroku issue, but it would help us solve your issue if you post the code of the affected file.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not because of Heroku, it's basically because there is a file in your command handler that doesn't have a name while handling it, as example like this code over here:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (Client, message, args, prefix) => {
    message.channel.send("pong")
}

module.exports.help = {
    // here the name isn't included
    aliases: ["p"]
}

// so just check if you have a file without a name while handling it and put a name, and if you don't want aliases make it `aliases: []`
```

This command handler should be like this
Commands Folder **commands** > Subfolder e.g. Moderation >  kick.js
Thats how it works, also thank you for watching my videos, I'm UltraX :)